# Print ("test ") does not work in QGIS Python Console

Tags: python, qgis-2, qgis-python-console

I have troubles with the Python Console in QGIS 2.18.23. When I type something like

```
Print ("test ")
```

and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, nothing happens and nothing is shown in the Python Console.

System configuration: Windows 8.1 64 bits

Comment: Isnt qgis 2.18 python 2.x? Then correct syntax is `print "test"`

Comment: What happen in you if do your `print('test')` in a python file and you execute it. Use the python code editor button in the python widget.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please add information about your operating system and installation type. Do Python plugins work for you?

Comment: i tried with `print "test" ` but it don't work, I

Comment: @bera `print(somestring)` is valid in python 2

Comment: OK, i resolve it was an plugin i disabled it and restart Qgis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether your Python is properly installed on your Windows OS.
Go to `cmd` and type `python --version`. Also, check whether you can access Python 2.x through the command line without QGIS. In `cmd` just type `python`.

`Print()` is not a valid function in the sense of Python syntax.

Since you are working with QGIS 2.18, it is based on Python 2.x.

Therefore the needed function should be called properly, and your desired statement might look like:

`print ("test ")` or alternatively `print "test "`

There are some articles which may be interesting for you:

- [Tutorial about print function in Python](https://www.python-course.eu/print.php)
- [Python 2.7 docs, built-in function: print()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print)
- [What is the difference between print and print() in python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996749/what-is-the-difference-between-print-and-print-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 0):

First of all the fist letter mast be lowercase:

```
print ("test ")
```

Do you try alternative build of QGIS by NextGIS? This installation not affected current QGIS install and has nice autoupdate functionality.

See http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

[image]